# Long Rotated x labels on the heatmap function in Julia Lang's Plots.jl is cut off from the figures, how to rescale?

Tags: julia, heatmap, axis-labels, plots.jl

I am using `Julia Lang` with the `Plots.jl` package to plot the values in a matrix with the `heatmap` function. Some of the variable names are quite long and cannot be shortened. The function will scale the figure to accommodate for the long names on the y-axis but not for the x-axis. An example is provided below. Is there an attribute or setting which can allow for the figure to overall scale according to the height including the labels? I have produced figures in .png and .pdf and the same effect is seen.

[image: heatmapExample]